# Using Pandas to merge .csv files

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, csv, pandas

Hope you can help me out with this one because it is really slow. Is there a way to do this without loading the whole .csv into memory?

The thing is... I have files containing timeseries data with 10 columns.
First column is a datetime, last an integer, and the rest are floats

I am trying to join two .csv files together. The filenames are:

- Myfile_1withdata
- Myfile_1withdata1
- Myfile_2withdata
- Myfile_2withdata1
- Myfile5_1withdata
- Myfile5_1withdata1

etc...

The files with a "1" at the end is the new file containing updated data that I want to add (append) to files without 1 at the end like "Myfile5_1withdata.csv"

Files can weight up to 500MB and there are many of them and it takes a long time to finish this process... Can it be faster?

Currently I have tried accomplish this by doing:

```
import inspect
import pandas as pd
import glob, os

currentpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))

type_names = {'1withdata':"super",'2withdata':"extra"}
file_names = ["Myfile","Myfile5"]

for a in file_names:
    for x in type_names.keys():
        results = pd.DataFrame([])
        for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob(str(a)+'_'+str(x)+"*")):
            namedf = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0,skiprows=0,dtype=str, usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],float_precision='high')
            results = results.append(namedf) # Dataframe with data of all file_names files with the same type_names key
        print("saving: ",a,x)
        results = results[~results.index.duplicated(keep='last')] #Remove duplicate row (last row with incomplete timeseries data)
        results.to_csv(a+'_'+str(x)+'.csv')
        print("DONE!")

#Cleanup by deleting data files with updated data (the ones ending with numbers)
files = [file for file in glob.glob(currentpath+"//*.csv") if file[-5:-4].isdigit() == True]
for file in files:
    os.remove(file)
```

**@Edit 1 :**

Here's an example of the data inside the files:

Myfile_1withdata.csv

```
The_Date_Time,Float1,Float2,Float3,Float4,Float5,Float6,Float7,Float8,Integer
31/10/2001 22:00:00,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,123456
30/11/2001 22:00:00,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,123456
31/12/2001 22:00:00,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,123456
31/01/2002 22:00:00,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,123456
28/02/2002 22:00:00,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,123456
```

Myfile_1withdata1.csv

```
The_Date_Time,Float1,Float2,Float3,Float4,Float5,Float6,Float7,Float8,Integer
28/02/2002 22:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
31/03/2002 22:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
30/04/2002 21:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
31/05/2002 21:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
30/06/2002 21:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
31/07/2002 21:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
```

So after the whole operation the Myfile_1withdata.csv should look like:

```
The_Date_Time,Float1,Float2,Float3,Float4,Float5,Float6,Float7,Float8,Integer
31/10/2001 22:00:00,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,123456
30/11/2001 22:00:00,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,123456
31/12/2001 22:00:00,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,123456
31/01/2002 22:00:00,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,1.11111,123456
28/02/2002 22:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
31/03/2002 22:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
30/04/2002 21:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
31/05/2002 21:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
30/06/2002 21:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
31/07/2002 21:00:00,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,1.22222,678910
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to parse the files at all? Can't you just append the rows blindly without converting them to lists (possibly handling the headers separately)?

Comment: More generally, can you show us an example of the first few lines of a file and its "1 at the end" version?

Comment: `#Cleanup by deleting data files with updated data (the ones ending with numbers)` If all my expierience with handling data has learned me anything, it's `don't touch your raw data`.  Instead of overwriting the original, export it to another directory or something

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your responses.
I posted answers to your question under "edit" in my post. Sure I can append the rows blindly without checking the original file. The only problems are: Updated file also contains headers on the first row, which would need be deleted/skipped, and the last line of the original file need be replaced by first line of the updated file.

Comment: can you provide some duplicated data in your example data and explain what should happen with the duplicates depending on the condition?

Comment: or is this check for duplication just in case that you add the second file twice? If so, I would even more strongly advise you not to overwrite the original file, but write it to a another file

Answer (score 2):

It is better to divide the problem in different parts:
Here that's:

- finding out what files need to be combined
- combining the data
- writing the output

Easiest to do this is using a chain of generators, akin to how in- and output is piped between different unix commands

## current directory

For finding files, `pathlib.Path` is the easiest way in most cases

```
from pathlib import Path


data_dir = Path('.')
```

## searching which files need to be combined:

`re` and `itertools.groupby` to the rescue

```
import re
import itertools
my_pattern = re.compile(r'Myfile(\d*)_(\d*)withdata(\d*)')

def find_files(data_dir):
    for file in data_dir.glob('*.csv'):
        yield my_pattern.match(file.name).groups(), file

def group_files(files):
    sorted_files = sorted(files)
    for group, data in itertools.groupby(sorted_files, key=lambda x: x[0][:2]):
        yield group, list(data)
```

This groups and sorts the data according to the numbers present

> ```
> file_data = [
>     (('', '2', ''), 'file0',),
>     (('', '2', '1'), 'file1',),
>     (('', '1', ''), 'file2',),
>     (('', '1', '1'), 'file3',),
>     (('1', '2', '1'), 'file4',),
>     (('1', '2', '1'), 'file5',),
> ]
>
> list(group_files(file_data))
>
> [(('', '1'), [(('', '1', ''), 'file2'), (('', '1', '1'), 'file3')]),
>  (('', '2'), [(('', '2', ''), 'file0'), (('', '2', '1'), 'file1')]),
>  (('1', '2'), [(('1', '2', '1'), 'file4'), (('1', '2', '1'), 'file5')])]
> ```

## Combining the data

```
def read_file(file):

    return pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0, skiprows=0, dtype=str, usecols=range(10), float_precision='high')
```

you can use [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update the info

```
def combine_files(grouped_files):
    for group, data in grouped_files:
        master_data_file = data.pop()[1]  # The one without suffix will always be last
        master_data = read_file(master_data_file)

        for info, file in data:
            data = read_file(file)
            master_data = master_data.update(data, overwrite=True, raise_conflict=False)
        yield group, master_data
```

### alternative combine

If, as @Mathias Ettinger states the `update` doesn't add new keys, you can try something like this:

```
def combine_files(grouped_files):

    dataframes = (read_file(filename) for group, (detail, filename) in grouped_files)
    result = pd.concat(dataframes).drop_duplicates(subset=<important_columns or index>, keep='last')
    yield group, result
```

This might mess with the column order. If this is a problem, you'll have to `reindex` the result with the wanted column order

## write the results

```
def write_results(combined_data):
    for group, data in combined_data:
        filename = 'result_Myfile{}_{}withdata.csv'.format(*group)
        data.to_csv(filename)
```

Comment: If I understand the documentation of `DataFrame.update` correctly, this won't add new timestamps to the original data, only update existing ones, right?

Comment: I have not used that function for this purpose, and without sample data it's hard to test. `overwrite : boolean, default True

    If True then overwrite values for common keys in the calling frame
` seems to suggest you can overwrite. If not, this part of the function should be replaced by a `concat` and `drop_duplicates`

Comment: Yes, you can overwrite, it seems to be the point of the function, but it also seems you can't extend the original dataframe with new indexes; which, to me, would defeat the purpose of the script.

Comment: Really sorry but I'm having a hard time using your functions correctly. Just trying to list the files gives an error " AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'glob' ". I tried print([x for x in find_files( os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])))]) and if using from pathlib import Path
data_dir = Path('.') 
print([x for x in find_files(data_dir)])
it returns an empty list " [] "

Comment: `Path('.')` normally points to the working directory from where you launched the script. If you need some other directory you'll need to adapt this path. You can see where it is pointed exactly by doing `print(data_dir.resolve())`. Instead of `[x for x in <generator>]` you can use `list(<generator>)`. You can test the glob by doing `list(p.glob(<pattern>))`. You might have toadapt the pattern,possibly by adding [`**/`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) to it to make the glob recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of retrieving the directory of the script is unusual, you may want to use the `__file__` magic variable populated when importing or running your script instead of relying on the `inspect` module.

The use of `glob.glob` in a for loop seems like a waste of resources, you may want to consider [`glob.iglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) instead.

You also happen to *not* use the values of the `type_names` dictionary, so why bother storing them? I would also turn the script into a function that accept both kind of names as parameters to ease reusability and testing.

Lastly, you use the `currentpath` variable when removing files but not when combining them, you may want to fix that.

```
import os
import glob

import pandas as pd


CURRENT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


def combine_csv(prefix):
    result = pd.DataFrame([])
    for file in glob.iglob(prefix + '*'):
        namedf = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0, skiprows=0, dtype=str, usecols=range(10), float_precision='high')
        result = result.append(namedf)
    result = result[~result.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
    result.to_csv(prefix + '.csv')


def main(file_names=('MyFile', 'MyFile5'), type_names=('1withdata', '2withdata')):
    for name in file_names:
        for kind in type_names:
            file_prefix = '{}_{}'.format(name, kind)
            combine_csv(os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, file_prefix))
            print('Saved', file_prefix + '.csv')

    for file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, '*.csv')):
        if os.path.splitext(file)[0][-1].isdigit():
            os.remove(file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Tried your code with 4 files = "Myfile_1withdata" / "Myfile_1withdata1" and "Myfile5_1withdata" / "Myfile5_1withdata1" The data in "Myfile" joined correctly in resulting .csv "Myfile_1withdata" but there's also another csv created "MyFile_2withdata" with nothing but empty string in it. The "Myfile5" data did not merge... "Myfile5_1withdata" is the same. And "MyFile5_2withdata" is created with empty string. All I would like to have left is just the "Myfile_1withdata" and "Myfile5_1withdata" and the files with 1 at the end of the name so "Myfile_1withdata1" and "Myfile5_1withdata1" deleted